# Split string in macro

Tags: c++, string, split, macros

I've a class name with its namespace, like `BasicType::MyType`.

It's possible to create a macro that split the name and uses only the part after the scope operator (I want to create a `MyType` object in macro without the first part)?

EDIT:

I'm using a library with different classes in namespace `BasicType`:

```
BasicType::ClassA
BasicType::ClassB
...
```

In order to use these classes, I need to register them. I must register them with another class, and it wants the name of the class, without the namespace:

```
BasicType::ClassA classa;
masterClass.register("ClassA", classa);
```

In order to use them in a template (because I must use many class of this namespace), I'm creating a trait, automated with a macro (because with `ClassA` I also have `ClassAImpl`, `ClassATypeSupport` etc):

```
#define BASICTYPE_TRAITS(className) \
  template <> \
  struct DDSTraits<className> \
  { \
    using TypeSupportImpl = className##Impl; \
    using TypeSupport_var = className##TypeSupport; \
  };

template <typename T>
struct BASICTYPE_TRAITS
{

};
....
BASICTYPE_TRAITS(BasicType::ClassA) // after this I've my trait
```

Now I want to add in this trait a string with the name of the class, so I can use it to register the class in `masterClass`

Comment: Why do you need it ? it seems like a XY problem.

Comment: Why not accept _two_ parameters to a macro: namespace name and class name? `BASICTYPE_TRAITS(BasicType, ClassA)`

Comment: Ok I'm stupid (I can say tired but it should not be the truth...). Please say it as answer so I can accept it. Thanks

Comment: you could also `use namespace BasicType` locally to avoid having to specify the namespace at all

Comment: Unfortunately I can't due to namespace pollution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change your macros so that it will accept *two* parameters: the namespace name and the class name. Something like

```
#define BASICTYPE_TRAITS(namespaceName, className) \
  template <> \
  struct DDSTraits<namespaceName::className> \
  { \
    using TypeSupportImpl = namespaceName::className##Impl; \
    using TypeSupport_var = namespaceName::className##TypeSupport; \
  };

template <typename T>
struct BASICTYPE_TRAITS
{

};
....
BASICTYPE_TRAITS(BasicType, ClassA) // after this I've my trait
```